# how to print field between the double quote

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I have the following file `conf.txt`:

```
perl /home/site/gen.pl  "GG - W C1 Test - sai1" "15072" && ssh 13.4.93.103 
perl /home/site/gen.pl  "GG - W C1 Test - sai2" "15072" && ssh     13.4.93.104 
perl /home/site/gen.pl  "GG - W C1 Test - sai3" "15072" && ssh 13.4.93.105
```

how to print the third field - between the "...." ,

for example

```
GG - W C1 Test - sai1
GG - W C1 Test - sai2
GG - W C1 Test - sai3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `awk`:

```
awk -F'"' '{ print $2 }' conf.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

```
cut -d\" -f2 <infile >outfile
```

That's all you need.